# Can't start network.service after removing NetworkManager

Tags: centos, networking, networkmanager

I have this problem that I can't fin a solution on the internet.
I have a centos 7 server with cpanel and whm. I deleted the NetworkManager and wanted to turn on network.service. Then I always get this error:

```
Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


[root@b1ca0 ~]# systemctl status network.service
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-01-31 10:34:31 EST; 8s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 13807 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: network.service failed.
```

```
  [root@b1ca0 ~]# journalctl -u network
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-01-31 10:30:42 EST, end at Thu 2019-01-31 10:43:29 EST. --
Jan 31 10:30:52 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Jan 31 10:30:53 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[2894]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Jan 31 10:30:57 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[2894]: Bringing up interface eth0:  INFO      : [ipv6_wait_tentative] Waiting for interface eth0 IPv6 address(es) to leave the 'tentative' state
Jan 31 10:30:57 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt ipv6_wait_tentative[3335]: Waiting for interface eth0 IPv6 address(es) to leave the 'tentative' state
Jan 31 10:30:58 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[2894]: INFO      : [ipv6_wait_tentative] Waiting for interface eth0 IPv6 address(es) to leave the 'tentative' state
Jan 31 10:30:58 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt ipv6_wait_tentative[3340]: Waiting for interface eth0 IPv6 address(es) to leave the 'tentative' state
Jan 31 10:30:59 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[2894]: Error: inet prefix is expected rather than "2A02:7B40:5928:BA7::1/64".
Jan 31 10:30:59 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[2894]: [  OK  ]
Jan 31 10:31:00 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[2894]: Bringing up interface prl_nettool-nm-eth0:
Jan 31 10:31:00 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[3406]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x5f0efd47)
Jan 31 10:31:07 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[3406]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x5f0efd47)
Jan 31 10:31:18 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[3406]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x5f0efd47)
Jan 31 10:31:29 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[3406]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x5f0efd47)
Jan 31 10:31:43 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[3406]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x5f0efd47)
Jan 31 10:32:01 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[2894]: Determining IP information for eth0... failed.
Jan 31 10:32:01 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[2894]: [FAILED]
Jan 31 10:32:01 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 31 10:32:01 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Jan 31 10:32:01 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Jan 31 10:32:01 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: network.service failed.
Jan 31 10:33:29 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Jan 31 10:33:30 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Jan 31 10:33:30 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: Bringing up interface eth0:  RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:33:30 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: Error: inet prefix is expected rather than "2A02:7B40:5928:BA7::1/64".
Jan 31 10:33:30 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: [  OK  ]
Jan 31 10:33:30 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: Bringing up interface prl_nettool-nm-eth0:
Jan 31 10:33:30 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[14056]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x612ef43c)
Jan 31 10:33:37 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[14056]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x612ef43c)
Jan 31 10:33:50 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[14056]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x612ef43c)
Jan 31 10:34:04 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[14056]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x612ef43c)
Jan 31 10:34:19 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[14056]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x612ef43c)
Jan 31 10:34:28 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt dhclient[14056]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x612ef43c)
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: Determining IP information for eth0... failed.
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: [FAILED]
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt network[13807]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Jan 31 10:34:31 b1ca0.k.dedikuoti.lt systemd[1]: network.service failed.
```

```
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="none"
HWADDR="00:00:59:28:0b:a7"
IPADDR="89.40.11.167"
NETMASK="255.255.255.255"
DHCPV6C="no"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6ADDR="2A02:7B40:5928:BA7::1/64"
GATEWAY="169.254.0.1"
IPV6_DEFAULTGW="fe80::ffff:1:1"
```

```
[root@b1ca0 network-scripts]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:59:28:0b:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 89.40.11.167/32 brd 89.40.11.167 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a02:7b40:5928:ba7::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::200:59ff:fe28:ba7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89112/discussion-on-question-by-raulis-radziukas-cant-start-network-service-after-rem).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to check if you actually disabled the NetworkManager:

```
# nmcli device status

# systemctl list-unit-files | grep NetworkManager
```

You then must check the NM parameter in the interfaces by editing the corresponding file.

Centos uses the Consistent Network Device Naming that's why you should not be suprised if you do not see ethX.

Go to the configuration file

```
# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enpXsX
```

And type the following:

```
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

I noticed that you are trying to use DHCP, I would recomend to try using a static IP address.

Example:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=ens160
UUID=666666666645664654654654
DEVICE=ens160
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.125.10
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.125.1
DNS1=192.168.125.48
DNS2=8.8.8.8
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

To set the DNS you will have to modify the file /etc/resolv.conf

And then try to restart and to enable the network service:

```
systemctl restart network    
systemctl enable network
```